# Laravel Search for German License Plates

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent

I could not find anything related to this topic that's why I am asking.

I need to build a search for german license plates. The can be very various. It is possible that they are saved like this RR-NN 999 or like this RR NN 999

The RR can be 2 or 3 letters wide, then there is the possibility to habe a '-' or a ' ' next, then there can be 'NN' or 'N' and after the space there is a number between 1 to 4 digits. Is it possible to search for a license plate with only one query? I am using laravel eloquent by the way.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense for you to store the license plate numbers normalized in a common format in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, for your example of RRNN999.

You should replace the Rs, Ns and digits with your actual search value.

```
LicensePlate::where('plate_number', 'REGEXP', '^RR[\- \ ]?N[\- \ ]?N[\- \ ]?999$')->get();
```

Comment: Okay.. some possible License plate could be: HH-AR 123, B AK 5678, WHV T 12; OD FF 1; I think it will be damn hard to get this with one regex expression, thought about it. I will just add the - or remove it and then i need to querys and need to put them together somehow

Comment: I think regexp is by far the best solution. I thought of an even simpler and more flexible pattern you can use: `^W.?H.?V.?T.?1.?2$` for WHVT12, basically just add a `.?` between each character